# Star Component Map method

Tags: css, reactjs

First of all i am new to ReactJs, i have to create a 5 star review component with half star rating also which i have implemented in Angular5,

Inside map method i have to loop the following elements

```
 <!-- full star -->
 <input 
      id="'star'+num"
      value="num-0.5"
      name="rating" 
      type="radio" />
 <label className="full"></label>
 <!-- half star -->
 <input
   value="num-0.5"
   id="'halfstar'+num" 
   name="rating" 
   type="radio"  />
 <label className="half"> </label>
```

this returns an error as it needs a wrapper div element, but if we use a div the css star review won't work as i took this from the following example:

https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

In Angular it's implemented using ng-container see example below:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/star-ratings-system-with-firestore/

Is there a way to solve this in React.

Comment: You can use react 16.. which can return multiple elements from render.

Comment: do you mean using react16 we can avoid wrapper div element inside map operator?

Comment: Yes i mean the same.

Comment: i will check with react16, thanks @Cyril.

Answer (score 0):

In React class keyword is reserved to declare components.  So you have to use className in JSX tags. Wrap your code inside div and use className instead of class and it should work

Working example below

```
 <div>
      <input 
         id="'star'+num"
         value="num-0.5"
         name="rating" 
         type="radio" />
     <label className="full"></label>

     <input
          value="num-0.5"
        id="'halfstar'+num" 
        name="rating" 
        type="radio"  />
    <label className="half"> </label>
  </div>
```

You can even return without div when you upgrade to React V16 and they called fragments. You can also return strings. Check docs here for details  https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html

But you have to set key to each element for better performance and to avoid warning.

The fragment return structure is basically an array like

```
return [
     <input />
     <input />
 ]
```

Comment: Sorry that was not i am talking about, the html i put here is to show the content only.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by here to show only content. From your question I understand that it’s not working if  elements are not wrapped inside div and css styles are not applied. What do you mean css star review won’t work?

Comment: BTW if you want to add your css styles which is in code pen you can import that in index.html. And

Comment: Hi, i only saw your comments with className in jsx when i commented, have to check with  react 16, thanks.

Comment: My question here is Even without v16 you can achieve it by wrapping it in div and changing class to className. Forget about v16. Are you facing any issue by just wrapping it inside div and changing class to className?

Comment: of course i can achieve it but the html layout will change and the css won't work in that case.

Comment: You can do it but looping will not be possible as the html is not written in that way. To make it to work in react 15 , you either have to change the html and css that way or  use complete html directly in your render .React 16 of course can do this.

Comment: Thanks @stack26, got some error when i upgraded from react 15 to 16, so stuck with it:
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactMount' .